# Spring WebFlux and MVC config in the same library

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm looking for a way to implement a "switch" in my library so that it would be able to work in 2 modes - reactive and blocking.
As of now i have two libraries doing basically the same thing - set of filters and interceptors and a factory providing end user with preconfigured WebClient/RestTemplate, Authentication and Authorization.

I found that `SpringApplication.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.REACTIVE)` is supposed to force application to run in either a reactive or an mvc mode. However, when i add mvc-dependency i can see in log that Tomcat is being chosen as a container to run the app

```
Starting service [Tomcat]
```

Here's my pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And the Application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        app.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.REACTIVE);
        app.run(args);
    }
}
```

Am i doing something wrong or the property is not supposed to allow switching between Netty and Tomcat to start with?

Comment: Tomcat supports reactive (as long as you use a proper version). Netty only supports Reactive and not the MVC part. I'm not certain you can use both at the same time, haven't tried that.

Comment: @M.Deinum yup, thx, the app seems to still be reactive even with the -web dependency on the classpath and when running on Tomcat. I just wish there was a way to manually select the web server within java code. Spring docs here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html suggest i exclude the default dependency to use another embedded server.

Comment: The web server or being reactive are 2 different things. As already shown by selecting Tomcat you can be both reactive and non-reactive. Same applies to Jetty (and I believe some extend Undertow). Netty is only a non-blocking runtime and supports only WebFlux .

Comment: Yeah, i know that Netty doesn't equal to reactive, since new versions of Tomcat also provide reactive support. It's just that my other services are already using Netty as it is Webflux default web server. Anyway, turns out i can force Netty usage programmatically by providing a configured NettyReactiveWebServerFactory bean.